# get server stats from a specfic time

Tags: linux, centos, logging

On my server this morning I noticed that an application reported it was running slow.

I checked the web and sql logs and found nothing special.

I would like to know what was going on at about 2am this morning.

Im looking for specifically the cpu and memory stats but im not sure where CentOS6 stores the logs.

I have checked in /var/log/ however cannot find any ;lo

Can anyone tell me where I might able to fine them?

Comment: What makes you think CentOS 6 stores CPU and memory logs (without you configuring a monitoring system that logs something like this)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have sysstat installed on your Centos6 you should have sar logs in

> /var/log/sa

You can view those with [sar](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=sysstat) command.

Other than that I would recommend installing [atop](http://atoptool.nl/); and running atop daemon. It will provide you with system state snapshots in 10 min intervals. If you need more frequent snapshots it can easily be adjusted.

Once setup you can easily view interval with something like

> atop -r snapshot_file -b 14:00 -e 15:00

which would start top like tool that would show interval between 14 and 15h.

Comment: why did I get down vote here ?